# How to use keyframes with styled from material-ui/styles

Tags: material-ui

Any example how to use keyframes with styled from material-ui/styles?

It's discussed [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/14066) for the withStyles function, but not for the styled function. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nuw9t) is the related sandbox example. Maybe someone could do the equal with the styled function?

Comment: this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/58958349/7412827

Comment: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69309765/12104850) for a MUI v5 solution